# Still having problems with GDPR T&C in Contributions

Tags: extension, gdpr

Our provider has applied the latest patch (issue #198) to Veda Consulting's GDPR extensions (V2.7) in an effort to get the T&C's working correctly on Events and Contributions. It seems to have fixed the problem with *Events*, but I am unable to get the *Contributions* setup to work correctly. Specifically on the Terms & Conditions page, for the "Enable terms and Conditions Acceptance" I can check either Yes or No, link a file, but when I click on Save, the Yes or No is cleared (along with everything else on that page) leaving the default settings in the GDPR setup to determine what happens. That does not happen with the same section on Events, which works correctly. Are we missing something? Anyone else with this problem?